# A good attitude, that's what counts. --- Good attitude is an appositive?

Tags: comma-splices, appositives

> A good attitude, that's what counts.

At first I saw this and thought *comma splice*; but that can't be because a splice requires two clauses.

In this sentence "a good attitude" is in apposition to the pronoun "that;" that's why this sentence is grammatically correct? (if I'd divided these two clauses by a comma *then* I'd be splicing with a comma.)

Comment: This is called "Left-Dislocation", and moves the subject to the beginning of the sentence, in a constituent of its own, followed by the rest of the sentence, but with a coreferential pronoun subject. "Right-Dislocation" works in the other direction, often with different intonation, and thus punctuation: _That's what counts -- a good attitude._ Both are transformations of _What counts is a good attitude_. Which is itself a pseudo-cleft transformation of _A good attitude counts._ See how sentences swell up?

Comment: Hey, @JohnLawler is there a good web site for the technical terms you refer to in questions like this? Maybe a linguistics wiki?

Comment: Here's [a list of the top 200-plus English transformations](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf), with examples.

Answer (score 2):

As John Lawler states in the comments:

> This is called "Left-Dislocation", and moves the subject to the beginning of the sentence, in a constituent of its own, followed by the rest of the sentence, but with a coreferential pronoun subject. "Right-Dislocation" works in the other direction, often with different intonation, and thus punctuation: That's what counts -- a good attitude. Both are transformations of What counts is a good attitude. Which is itself a pseudo-cleft transformation of A good attitude counts. See how sentences swell up?
>
> Here's [a list of the top 200-plus English transformations](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf), with examples.