# Left-dislocation of a content clause, or just a comma splice?

Tags: comma-splices

Consider the following sentences, which all have the pattern

*X, that's what I say*.

where *X* is a complete clause:

[1a] *Nobody ever got something for nothing, that's what I say.* ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=BvlHsyuT3SkC&pg=PA205&dq=%22that%27s+what+I+say%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh-dCy1fnKAhVLkx4KHe4JBcQQ6AEIrwEwGA#v=onepage&q=%22that%27s%20what%20I%20say%22&f=false))

[1b] *The previous spring's where it's born, that's what I say.* ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=r8l4mJSzk0cC&lpg=PA27&dq=%22that's%20what%20I%20say%22&pg=PA28#v=onepage&q=%22that's%20what%20I%20say%22&f=false); scroll up)

[1c] *She'd be a fool to turn ye down, that's what I say.* ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q4lzBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA282&dq=%22that%27s+what+I+say%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh-dCy1fnKAhVLkx4KHe4JBcQQ6AEItwIwLw#v=onepage&q=%22that%27s%20what%20I%20say%22&f=false))

[1d] *Never trust an ethnic restaurant full of white people, that's what I say.* ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=MHXQBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT13&dq=%22that%27s+what+I+say%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh-dCy1fnKAhVLkx4KHe4JBcQQ6AEI2gIwNQ#v=onepage&q=%22that%27s%20what%20I%20say%22&f=false))

[1e] *Let them know that they've got to be afraid of you, that's what I say.* ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=fkiL8Gdm3HwC&pg=PT79&dq=%22that%27s+what+I+say%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh-dCy1fnKAhVLkx4KHe4JBcQQ6AEIqAMwQw#v=onepage&q=%22that%27s%20what%20I%20say%22&f=false))

They all seem to be related to a corresponding pseudo-cleft in which *X* becomes a content clause, namely,

*What I say is that X*.

So, for example, we have

[2a] *What I say is that nobody ever got something for nothing.*

and similarly for the other examples.

Now, this reminds me of **left-dislocation**, as discussed in [another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231562/a-good-attitude-thats-what-counts-good-attitude-is-an-appositive) on the English stackexchange:

[3] *A good attitude, that's what counts.*

This is, apparently, a straightforward case of a left-dislocation of

[4] *What counts is a good attitude.*

However, all examples of dislocation I've seen discussed so far involve a dislocation of a noun phrase (such as *a good attitude*). True, [CGEL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0582517346), for one, says only that dislocation *usually* involves an NP (p. 1408), so presumably other things could be dislocated as well. In full, CGEL says

> A dislocated clause has a constituent, usually an NP, located to the
>   left or right of the nucleus of the clause, with an anaphorically
>   linked pronoun or comparable form within the nucleus itself.

It *seems* to me like the examples [1a]-[1e] *could* fit this definition...

One specific thing that worried me for a time about the left-dislocation theory in the case of the examples [1a]-[1e] is  that the word *that* appears in both the non-dislocated and the (allegedly) dislocated sentences:

[1a'] *Nobody ever got something for nothing, **that** is what I say.*

[2a] *What I say is **that** nobody ever got something for nothing.*

In contrast, in the attested examples of left-dislocation, *that* only appears in the dislocated sentence:

[3] *A good attitude, **that** is what counts.*

[4] *What counts is a good attitude.*

However, I don't think that this superficial breaking of the [3] vs. [4] pattern matters. After all,  *that* in [2a] is a subordinator introducing the content clause, whereas in [1a'] it is a pronoun, just like in [3].

My real worry is that I haven't personally seen *any* attested examples of left-dislocation other than those of an NP. In fact, the predecessor of CGEL, [Quirk, Greenbaum, Leech, and Svartvik](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0582517346), says that *only* NPs feature in left-dislocation (p. 1310)... On the other hand, CGEL leaves the door open for other kinds, but it doesn't provide any examples. And as these two are my go-to sources at the moment, I don't know what to think.

So: are the examples [1a]-[1e] all instances of left-dislocation of a content clause? Or are they mere comma splices, so that one should really have, e.g.,

[5a] *Nobody ever got something for nothing; that's what I say.*

instead?

Comment: Nobody ever got something for nothing -- *which* is what has me worried.  A semantic rather than a grammatical antecedent?  pronoun **that**?

Comment: 5a seems correct to me. If you flip it, you have *That's what I say: nobody ever got something for nothing.* A comma doesn't work there either. However, *I don't know, nobody ever got something for nothing.* Comma splice? Interjection? Adverbial clause?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your examples involve left dislocation.  "That's what I say" is a separate, independent clause.  The written forms have some odd punctuation, but there is nothing very interesting going on there.

On the other hand, there are other constructions where sentences act like noun phrases.  "Joe sneezed, which surprised me."  There, the "coreferential" antecedent for the noun phrase "which" is the sentence "Joe sneezed".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Three questions: 

1. Just so that I understand: are you saying that the fact that _That's what I say_ is a separate, independent clause is _evidence_ that there is no left-dislocation, or a _consequence_ of the fact that there is nothing interesting here? I'm asking because _that's what counts._ can also be a separate clause, and yet _A good attitude, that's what counts_ is an example of left-dislocation. 

2. Are there examples of left-dislocation that don't involve an NP? 
3. So, are [1a]-[1e] comma splices?

Comment: I'm saying that your examples are not left-dislocations.  I didn't give any evidence -- I just don't think they are.  Maybe it's the intonation.  I could perfectly well write or say "A good attitude.  That's what counts." as two separate sentences.  Why think it is a single clause?

Comment: I don't know what a "comma splice" is.  I'll look it up.

Comment: Thanks. However, I thought 'A good attitude, that's what counts' is non-controversially a left dislocation...? What then about this one, from CGEL: 'Her parents, I don't like them at all.' Note that one could also separate them... but then it seems like one could separate any such thing, in which case there aren't any left dislocations at all? 

Moreover, one can separate sentence relative clauses, too: 'Perhaps she thinks it sounds better. Which it does really.' (example from British National Corpus, cited [here](http://goo.gl/flZEUZ)). Should we say all such things are really two sentences?

Comment: Perhaps we should.  The problem is that if these are single clauses, they are root sentences, so we can't put them inside other constructions to test the number of clauses.  Commenting on the derived structure of appositive clauses like your "... Which it does really.", McCawley says he attaches them to the preceding "out of habit" -- meaning I take it that he has no real evidence on the matter. //  For your CGEL example, if "Her parents." is given the intonation of an independent sentence, it means something different.

Answer (score 0):

'That is what I say', or 'That is what counts' are relative pronoun clauses.  The antecedent could be a complete sentence, or it could be a fragment.  A period should separate the former, and a comma the latter, or a semi-colon would be appropriate for either.